# Move player to exact touch/mouse click location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my 2D unity game, I am trying to move my sprite to the location of my touch/cursor (right now it's a mouse click).

My sprite is at the location (173, 48, -52.1).
However, when I click a location that is probably a few pixels away my position is changed to (399, 129, 0) and my sprite is apparently hurled into the vast unknown.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

    //fingerPos =  Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    fingerPos = Input.mousePosition;
    transform.position = fingerPos;
    Debug.Log(transform.position);
}
```

**EDIT**

Current code

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); //Desktop
        transform.position = fingerPos;
        Debug.Log (transform.position);
    }
```

**Update** . Apprantly, when I click the position that is recorded (and the one the sprite is moved to) is directly ON the camera. Refer to image
[image: Click]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform.position` is in world coordinates.
`Input.mousePosition`  returns values in pixel coordinates. You need to convert this into world coordinates.

```
fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position); //Mobile
fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); //Desktop
```

Then you can assign it to your position.

```
transform.position = fingerPos;
```

**EDIT**:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    fingerPos = Input.mousePosition;
    fingerPos.z = 10;
    fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerPos);

    transform.position = fingerPos;
    Debug.Log(transform.position);
}
```

Comment: Actually in reviewing, this does not work entirely correct. The character is moved to a specific spot on the screen.Not where I touched.

Comment: Your question **"my sprite is apparently hurled into the vast unknown"** That's because you are assigning pixel coordinate to world coordinate with `fingerPos = Input.mousePosition`. You must convert it to world coordinate like I did in my answer. That's the problem with your code. **this does not work entirely correct"** You are not even specific about what's not working. This should solve the problem of your sprite disappearing.

Comment: Where every I click on the screen, the coordinates returned to me in the debug log is the exact same. Please look at my code edit

Comment: Does the Sprite move to where you clicked on the screen?

Comment: No it doesnt, just to those fixed coordinates

Comment: The problem is from your camera mode. I modified it to work on both mode(Orthographic and Perspective).  Check the Edit.

Comment: Can you explain what happened with the cameras?

Comment: You have to specify the Z distance. This is properly explained [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/331576/view.html)